# MySQL Inserting data and setting FK's?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table like this in my database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsoS9.png

I have all my PK,FK relationships setup and im ready to start inserting data.

However I do not know where to start.

Do I insert into tables where my Primary Keys are first.

But then how do I give my Foreign keys the values of the primary key in the linking tables?

I thought with starting with:

```
-Patient
-Department
-Procedure
-Staff
-Events
    -Supplies
```

Any reference material would be appreciated, I tried googling my question but not luck. Perhaps someone could eloquote it more accurately.

Comment: You can look at the tutorials [here](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-tutorial.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You thought correctly, start with the foremost "parent" table, and work your way down. Inserting the foreign keys can be done either with nested queries or simply getting the key, storing it, and reusing it.

Personally I'd go with nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to logically populate the parent records first.  Obviously, you cannot insert a child record without having a parent existing first -- so long as you have true relationships between the two.  In your case, just as your diagram suggests, you'll need to populate `Events` before you can populate `Supplies`.  And then, what ever other logical ties you have.